# is not defined javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im getting this error 'is not defined' and i dont know how to fix this here's code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hash-Tag.io</title>
    <style type="text/css">
            canvas
            {
                background-image: url('background.png');
                border: 2px #000 solid;
            }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function draw (x,y) {
            var canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.save();
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500" height="500" onclick="draw(0,0);" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Please dont say jquery lib. is after the javascript becouse i tried it.

Comment: Actually, there is no import of the jquey lib.

Comment: You've didn't carefully read the answer from jcubic. It's either `document.getElementById("canvas")` or `document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]` (pay attention to the `[0]` as `.getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object)

Comment: This code means that your library is either in the root folder or the same folder as your JS code (depending on your implementation.) Where is the library exactly?

Comment: for future reference you may want to be more precise in your questions. In the code shown, the error wouldn't be `is not defined` ... it would be `canvas.getContext is not a function` ... in the original version of the question, the error would be `canvas is null` ... also, javascript would never output just `is not defined` - it would output something like `xxx is not defined` where xxx is some undefined variable you're trying to access. The more precise you are in a question, the less likely you'll need a mind reader to answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set id for canvas if you want to use getElementById:

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" onclick="draw(0,0);"></canvas>
```

or use:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
```

Comment: oh i forgot add id to canvas im so stupid but still getting this error

Comment: @user3189323 `getElementsByTagName` return arary like object (NodeList) you need to add `[0]` to get first element.